# log file is not being created by log4net dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

my code is,

```
<configSections>
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
```

then after webconfig tag]

```
<log4net debug="true">
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="c:\\ PeejayImpex.log"/>
  <!-- Example using environment variables in params -->
  <!-- <param name="File" value="${TMP}\\ApplicationKit.log" /> -->
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-2p %c [%x] - %m%n"/>
  </layout>
</appender>

<root>
  <level value="ALL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
</root>
```

it is done with no errors

then in global file

```
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup

    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
}
```

after this i wrote in pageload..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (log.IsErrorEnabled)
    {
        log.Info("Hello Nine Thanks for use Log4Net,This is info message");
        log.Debug("Hello Nine Thanks for use Log4Net,This is Debug message");
        log.Error("Hello Nine Thanks for use Log4Net,This is Error message");
        log.Warn("Hello Nine Thanks for use Log4Net,This is Warn message");
        log.Fatal("Hello Nine Thanks for use Log4Net,This is Fatal message");
        log.Debug("Did it again!");
    }
    }
```

i am using it first time idont know whats wrong please help me ,something is really missing as there's no errors eventhen log file is not created. 
:)

Comment: I think, by default, log4net will use the `app.config` for configuration. See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/823247/How-to-use-Apache-log-net-library-with-ASP-NET-MVC) to learn how to configure log4net to respect the `web.config`.

Comment: thank you so much gene for replying ,i noticed in debuggers output that access was denied to path i was using then i changed path and is working fine.